Should use async function and Promise to wait for returned data from BE
I have a tree, so when a user clicks on the root, the table will automatically display the first item of that root node.
The problem arises when the user clicks too quickly, even before the API tree returns data containing the first item.
So I came up with the idea:
so I came up with the idea
const getFirstItemAsync = useCallback(async () => {
    while (isEmpty(tree?.[0]?.items)) {
      await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    }
    return tree?.[0]?.items?.[0];
  }, [tree]);

And this is my function to fetch data tree
const loadItemsFn = useCallback(
    (item: A, targetId: string, isExpand: boolean = true) => {
      if (loadItems) {
        loadItems(params).then(
          (data: ITreePayload<ITreeItem>) => {
            setTree(data)
          }
        );
      }
    },
    [loadItems, tree ]
  );

However, I think there is a way to track when the API call is ready and await until the API has returned.

Please post the relevant code that does the fetching and how it is related to this component. You current code is just "sleeping" for 1second. So if after 1 second the fetch is not complete, you will have the same issue. How about disabling the button until the data are available ?

it's a tree component where is clickable, so can not disable the button

Then disable the tree component and give it a cursor of not-allowed or something? Doesn't really matter whether it's a button, you just want to prevent the user from interacting further until you have done your bit.

"The problem arises when the user clicks too quickly" - what problem specifically? What table and tree are you talking about? Do you mean data structures, UI components, or something else? Where are getFirstItemAsync and loadItemsFn called?

loadItemsFn automatically called when user first enter the app and I try to use getFirstITemAsync when user click the root tree and it will display the first item information on the table

You could do something like the following
const [isTreeLoading, setIsTreeLoading] = useState(false);
const loadItemsFn = useCallback(
    (item: A, targetId: string, isExpand: boolean = true) => {
      if (loadItems) {
        setIsTreeLoading(true);
        loadItems(params).then(
          (data: ITreePayload<ITreeItem>) => {
            setTree(data)
          }
        ).finally(()=>{
          setIsTreeLoading(false);
        })
      }
    },
    [loadItems, tree ]
  );

// now you can use the isTreeLoading variable whenever you want to 

This is a initial approach to this issue, just to give the general idea. In reality you should have to check/handle for errors of the request etc.
There are libraries that can provide much of this out of the box, like TanStack query (previously known as react-query)

You can use a state with a time out to prevent quick click of the user
const [isProcessing, setIsProcessing] = useState<boolean>(false);

const handleLoadItemsFn = async () => {
    if(isProcessing)
    {
        return;
    }
    setIsProcessing(true);
    try{
        loadItemsFn(); // pass your parameter
    }
    catch(error)
    {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIsProcessing(false);
        }, 1000);
    }
    finally
    {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setIsProcessing(false);
        }, 1000);
    }
}

